# Is it possible to remotely switch on Find My Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icloud, apple-id, find-my-mac

My MacBook was stolen over a month ago. I stupidly hadn’t enabled **Find My Mac**, so I was unable to track it. I’ve just had a notification saying that the stolen MacBook has logged into my iCloud account.

Surely there is some way I can trace it now? Any ideas would be amazing, it's so frustrating feeling so helpless!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot do this. Apple provides steps to [Set up Find My iPhone on all of your devices](https://support.apple.com/HT205362), all of which **require physical access to the device**.

Since the notification email you received should have included an IP address, you could always try remoting into your MacBook Pro using [Back To My Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204618), [Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop), or some [alternate method](https://www.howtogeek.com/180953/3-free-ways-to-remotely-connect-to-your-macs-desktop); and enabling **Find My Mac** that way.

However let’s face it: your chance of success here is *extremely* slim, and requires that you have allowed some kind of remote access to your MacBook prior to having it stolen.

Since the thief now has access to your iCloud account, your next step should be to head to [id.apple.com](https://id.apple.com/) and change your password immediately—before they do it for you.